# Как зашифровать методом RSA сообщение своим ключом?

Tags: python, криптография, rsa

Как зашифровать методом RSA сообщение своим ключом?

```
import rsa
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)

message = b'Hello world!'

# шифруем
crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, pubkey)
print(crypto)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос:  [How to encrypt a string using the key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1320671/4279)

Answer (score 3):

## [Шифрование с публичным ключом](http://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public/)

Если Алиса хочет послать Бобу сообщение, зашифрованное его открытым ключом, не подписывая сообщение, то нужен только публичный ключ Боба:

```
>>> # Generate keys on Bob's computer
>>> import nacl.encoding  # $ pip install pynacl
>>> import nacl.public
>>> skbob = nacl.public.PrivateKey.generate()
>>> skbob.public_key.encode(encoder=nacl.encoding.Base64Encoder)
b'eVNxqEZ1/cbiu8G+aep6OR+ccf2kZLKqDYGhtZPLnRg='
```

Получив этот ключ, Алиса может зашифровать своё сообщение для Боба:

```
>>> # Encrypt message on Alice's computer
>>> import nacl.encoding
>>> import nacl.public
>>> pkbob = nacl.public.PublicKey(b'eVNxqEZ1/cbiu8G+aep6OR+ccf2kZLKqDYGhtZPLnRg=', encoder=nacl.encoding.Base64Encoder)
>>> sealed_box = nacl.public.SealedBox(pkbob)
>>> message = b'hello world'
>>> sealed_box.encrypt(message, encoder=nacl.encoding.Base64Encoder)
b'jhh9bnv5boORCrnEVzKYxh6tMr7iJ9npzLRSpUXGAXXUuFUZQS9Y7UCSBVuyfGvA9suZ4rMDbRfBy0c='
```

Получив зашифрованное сообщение, Бобу легко его расшифровать:

```
>>> # Decrypt message on Bob's computer
>>> encrypted = b'jhh9bnv5boORCrnEVzKYxh6tMr7iJ9npzLRSpUXGAXXUuFUZQS9Y7UCSBVuyfGvA9suZ4rMDbRfBy0c='
>>> unseal_box = nacl.public.SealedBox(skbob)
>>> unseal_box.decrypt(encrypted, encoder=nacl.encoding.Base64Encoder)
b'hello world'
```

Приведённый код реализован на [Curve25519 примитивах на эллиптических кривых](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public/#algorithm).

*Обратите внимание:* в коде явно не упоминается ни один криптографический примитив. Чем меньше движущихся частей, которые нужно понимать, тем меньше шансов сломать что-то ненароком. См. [If You’re Typing the Letters A-E-S Into Your Code You’re Doing It Wrong](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

[`PyNaCl`](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/) это Питон-обёртка для [современной переносимой libsodium крипто-библиотеки](https://libsodium.org).

### RSA шифрование

Чтобы зашифровать сообщение именно RSA алгоритмом, используя публичный ключ из файла, [можно `M2Crypto` обёртку над OpenSSL использовать](https://pypi.org/project/M2Crypto/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
from M2Crypto import RSA  # $ pip install m2crypto

# ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m PKCS8 >id_rsa.pub.pem
rsa = RSA.load_pub_key('id_rsa.pub.pem')     # load public key
encrypted = rsa.public_encrypt(b'hello world', RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)  # encrypt
print(base64.b64encode(encrypted).decode())  # print as base64
```

*Обратите внимание:* здесь используетcя [требуемая для новых приложений](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7) RSAES-OAEP схема.

Чтобы расшифровать `encrypted_base64` сообщение, используя частный ключ из файла:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
import os
from M2Crypto import RSA  # $ pip install m2crypto

rsa = RSA.load_key(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa'))  # load private key
encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted_base64)  # get raw bytes
print(rsa.private_decrypt(encrypted, RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding).decode())  # decrypt
# -> hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример, используещий модуль PyCrypto:

```
In [2]: from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
   ...:
   ...: fn_priv = r'D:\temp\id_rsa'
   ...: fn_pub = r'D:\temp\id_rsa.pub'
   ...:
   ...: with open(fn_pub, 'rb') as pub, open(fn_priv, 'rb') as priv:
   ...:     key_pub = RSA.importKey(pub.read())
   ...:     key_priv = RSA.importKey(priv.read())
   ...:
   ...: encrypted = key_pub.encrypt(b'Hello world!', 111)
   ...:
   ...: decrypted = key_priv.decrypt(encrypted)
   ...:
   ...: print(encrypted)
   ...: print('=' * 60)
   ...: print(decrypted)
   ...:
(b'\xa7\xf1\x8b0\xe8\xcb|\xda\xb9F\\o_\xd5r\x07&\x92/S\x93\xb9\x91\xe9s({\x00\x93U\'\xe6_=M\x07PBI\xab!\xb2 |Fi\xca\xdf\x9d\xb9\x8fJ\x0f\xe6
\xc6\x14\xac\x15?)u\x15\xf6\xb8\xe2\xe8\xef\x8e$1\xe3\xa5v\xa0G<n~\xf0qJ\xd9\xfed\x8a\x15\xbb\xc8\xe0\xfdAiY\xde\xbdm\x8a\xd3x\x81\xea^3Z\xb
0b\x94N\x14\xf4L\x105\x8d\xf85\x98\xc0YC"\x11C\x9b\x97\x04b\xfd]O\xf9e<3\xc1\x82\xb8\xf9\xc3\xb5z\xfd:\x85\x00o*k\x03\x0088\xea\xc2h\xab\xcb
e\xe3\xba\xf8tdM\x96\xc5mD\xc6[\xe3\\\x15\xa28\x03\xe7bff\xaa#u\xa6gV\xc0X\xb7\xd2\xe1\xeb\xd2w\xf6\xe21\x95\x10r\x14=\x15UI\xe9S\x02!\xf9\x
cd\xa4\xd9\x10\xffp\x8fDb\x01Ofd!K0/\xe6\xd5\x16\x13\xf8\x1a^\xd4v"\xea\x89\xe7\x19\xbcu\x89\x11\xfc\x07\x0em7w\xbea\xae\x85\x81\x88Kbh\x8f\
xd6\xad\xca\x88\x9en\xa7\x94\xe9#\x1b4h\xde7k\x925!\x8f=\xf8\xafoa1\x90\xe2h\x10\x8e\xd6\xf4\xde\xc6bL\xaa\x1e\xa6$\xd2w\x8aQc\xecLL\xa7\xb2
\xacD\xe5("\x8c\'\xb8n\xf2uH\x7f\'\xa1\xd8\xf8}0jBNE6y\x871\x95\xa3\xfa\xa9]\xe49\xad/\xbe;*\xdb#\x14\x92\xe4\x1a\r\xb7X\xd7T\xb7\x82>\xa3\x
80y\xec\xf1c\x16\x15&u\x85O\xc5i\xcfCY\x17\x0fq\tI\x9f\x1e\x94_\x81\xb6\x1f\x0f\xc7\xa3\x8bL\xee\xf0_jA\xeea\x15\xa2{ )\xb9\x0c\x96\xaa\xea*
\x8c\xb4g\xd0&\xd1\x9b\x9d\xe3\xe4\xe1d\xa9zi\xe2\x8c\x93\xc8\'V#\xf24tEoXo\xc7\x01\xa2\x92\xb1\x9c\x1a\x0f\x10,\x99r)m\x85F\xcdO\xa3\xe1\x8
b\xc6\xd7\x0e\xc7l\x97u\x94&\x17\xd7\x18\x88\x9c9\xc0\x86\xcf\x1f\xf3yd\xfd=-BF\xdc\xeaj\xf7\xee\xf6$\x8e\xc4\x9c\xb6YCF+\x03\xcb\xe2',)
============================================================
b'Hello world!'
```

PS для данного примера я специально сгенерировал ключи без пароля, с длиной 4096 бит

Comment: документация говорит: [*"you should not directly encrypt data with this method"*](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt) (НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТОТ МЕТОД) и рекомендует [PKCS#1 OAEP](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html) (пример кода по ссылке)