# При попытки зашифровать через rsa возникает ошибка

Tags: python, rsa

Решил попробовать зашифровать текст, но возникает ошибка

Вот код:

```
import rsa

message = input("Text:")

pubkey = input("Public Key:")

crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, pubkey)

print(crypto)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\py\crp2\crp.py", line 7, in <module>
    crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, pubkey)
  File "C:\Users\Дом\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 169, in encrypt 
keylength = common.byte_size(pub_key.n)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Comment: что-то с входными данными

Comment: Очевидно, что публичный ключ это объект из модуля rsa, а не просто строка. Кст, попробуйте ключ так сгенерировать и проверить: `pubkey, privkey = rsa.newkeys(512)`

Comment: Да, так работает, но мне нужно использовать свой, а не сгенерированный ключ

Comment: связанный вопрос [RSA шифрование своим ключом на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590060/23044)